# I want to indicate an4chart bulletlabel as a blank

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

```
 var labelBullet = new am4charts.LabelBullet();
      series.bullets.push(labelBullet);
      labelBullet.label.text = "{valueY.value.formatNumber('#.#')}";
      labelBullet.strokeOpacity = 0;
      labelBullet.stroke = am4core.color('#dadada');
      labelBullet.dy = 0;
```

[image]

If the label bullets value of am4chart is continuously the same, I want to indicate it as a blank.
I checked console.log(labelBullet) but i can't find related it.
Please give me a favor.

i did checked labelBullet's values but i coudn't find related it.
and i coudn't find solution on am4chart documentaion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a combination of the `lableBullet.disabled` and `labelBullet.propertyFields.disabled` configuration:

```
labelBullet.disabled = true;
labelBullet.propertyFields.disabled = "disabled";
```

Here is a sandbox I created showing how this can be applied to your example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-a-75528252-bzflzo?file=/src/App.tsx:1648-1730

Comment: Thank you for your favor, Have a goodday